# Starting at EN2 6BQ (North London) on Wednesday noon which Capital Centre can you get to in the quickest time?

Tags: uk, europe, where-on-earth, routes

Excluding London.

You may use planes/trains/cars, but no privately chartered planes or helicopters.

You must take in to account how busy the roads will be at the time.

Comment: I have VTCed this question as this is too narrow in scope and is unlikely able to help any future travellers.

Comment: Travel.SE does occasionally take "trivia" questions, but I think this one would be better for http://puzzling.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Look for a UK bank or financial institution that styles its branches "Capital Centres".

Answer (score 4):

If you count time to get through airport security/time spent in the airport etc. trains/driving would be faster.

The fastest capital city you can reach would be Paris, as well as Cardiff, capital of Wales if you're looking inside the UK. On a Wednesday afternoon you could leave that postcode address at 12:18pm and arrive in Paris within 3 hours and 41 minutes, via trains & Eurostar  (including 30 minute check in time for Eurostar) ([Enfield to Pancreas](https://www.thetrainline.com/book/results?origin=9434b52de48650814fb147c7f59c2914&destination=aaa204eb20619a8f68a60ac75a752c11&outwardDate=2019-06-05T12%3A00%3A00&outwardDateType=departAfter&journeySearchType=single&passengers%5B%5D=1989-05-29&selectedOutward=s6%2FxFwJbyJ0%3D%3AQXthx2GfNHY%3D) at 12:18-12:59, [Eurostar](https://www.thetrainline.com/book/results?origin=aaa204eb20619a8f68a60ac75a752c11&destination=69b59b70a73b72302eff45627aeef377&outwardDate=2019-06-05T12%3A00%3A00&outwardDateType=departAfter&journeySearchType=single&passengers%5B%5D=1993-05-29%7C7575c2c9-950d-4f51-acca-c0fc9b72bcd6) from 13:31)

For Cardiff you would leave at 12:12 and be there for 15:23 via trains, 3hr 11 minutes, but since many class the UK as one 'country' instead of being made up of several countries I'm not sure if this is what you're after. ([source](https://www.google.com/search?ei=X4TuXOjOMcmk1fAPhYGZWA&q=en2%206bq%20to%20cardiff%20train%2012pm&oq=en2%206bq%20to%20cardiff%20train%2012pm&gs_l=psy-ab.3...36479.48566..48787...0.0..0.129.924.12j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j33i160._jJi-HzPMDg))

Comment: Using your own source, Brussels can be reached in 2hrs 56mins - 6 minutes faster!

Comment: Those times don't work at all for Paris - I think Google has some sort of bug! It has you arriving at St Pancras at 13:44 and departing at 13:31... This is one of many reasons I never use Google Maps for public transport planning.

Comment: @Muzer You're right I hadn't noticed! Edited with trainline.com info and updated the times

Comment: Have you allowed for the 30 minute check-in time for Eurostar? I cannot quite make your timetables match up.